# How to remove a rows using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

In the below shown sheet I had successfully done `worksheet.removeRow(row)` to clear out the unwanted rows.

[image]

This is how I was able to remove the unwanted rows

```
 public void removeRow(XSSFSheet worksheet, List<Row> toBeRemovedRows) {
    for (Row row : toBeRemovedRows) {
        worksheet.removeRow(row);
    }
 }
```

toBeRemovedRows contains all the rows except rows 9, 14 and 18.

As far I know `worksheet.shiftRows(startRow, endRow, -n);` does removing these unwanted rows physically. As per the above sheet I need to get rid of rows from 5-8, 10-13 and 15-17 (I want to keep the top 4 header related rows)

I want to shift these rows dynamically based on the toBeRemovedRows list.

How do I achieve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `public void removeRow(XSSFSheet worksheet, List<Row> toBeRemovedRows)` may run into concurrent modification exceptions as you are removing from a collection while iterating over that collection and do not use the iterator itself to remove. Furthermore to remove one should run bottom up instead top down to avoid problems with indexes of the items. For example if you have rows 1, 2, 3 and do removing row 2, then former row 3 will become row 2 after that and there is no row 3 anymore. This is not a problem here since `Sheet.removeRow` not really removes rows but only removes all content from rows. However, I recommend always removing items from bottom to top.

After the `Sheet.removeRow` was run, all "removed" rows are totally empty and are not in sheets internally file storage anymore. If one tries to get such rows using `Sheet.getRow`, one get a `null`. Knowing this, one could simply run bottom up over all rows of the sheet to get the row indexes of all filled rows, calculate the difference between this filled row and the previous found filled row. Then shift up this filled row as much rows as difference was calculated. After that only filled rows should be in sheet. To avoid loosing possible empty rows in header sections, one could end this process in a given first remaining row.

Example:

```
 void removeEmptyRows(Sheet sheet, int firstRemainingRow) {
  int previousFilledRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  for (int i = sheet.getLastRowNum(); i >= firstRemainingRow; i--) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
   if (row != null) {
    int thisFilledRow = row.getRowNum();
    int shift = thisFilledRow - previousFilledRow + 1;
    System.out.println("this: " + thisFilledRow);
    System.out.println("previous: " + previousFilledRow);
    System.out.println("shift: " + shift);
    if (shift < 0) {
     sheet.shiftRows(previousFilledRow, sheet.getLastRowNum(), shift);   
    }
    previousFilledRow = thisFilledRow;
   }
  }
 }
```

Complete example for testing:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ExcelReadShiftRowsAndWrite {
    
 static List<Row> getToBeRemovedRows(Sheet sheet, DataFormatter dataFormatter, int columnIdx, String criteria) {
  List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>();
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   String foundCriteria = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(columnIdx));
   if (foundCriteria.equals(criteria)) {
    result.add(row);
   }       
  }
  return result;
 }   

 static void removeRows(Sheet sheet, List<Row> toBeRemovedRows) {
  for (int i = toBeRemovedRows.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   sheet.removeRow(toBeRemovedRows.get(i));
  }
 }

 static void removeEmptyRows(Sheet sheet, int firstRemainingRow) {
  int previousFilledRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
  for (int i = sheet.getLastRowNum(); i >= firstRemainingRow; i--) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
   if (row != null) {
    int thisFilledRow = row.getRowNum();
    int shift = thisFilledRow - previousFilledRow + 1;
    System.out.println("this: " + thisFilledRow);
    System.out.println("previous: " + previousFilledRow);
    System.out.println("shift: " + shift);
    if (shift < 0) {
     sheet.shiftRows(previousFilledRow, sheet.getLastRowNum(), shift);   
    }
    previousFilledRow = thisFilledRow;
   }
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //String fileIn= "./TestIn.xls"; String fileOut= "./TestOut.xls";
  String fileIn= "./TestIn.xlsx"; String fileOut= "./TestOut.xlsx";

  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(fileIn));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOut)) {
           
   DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
   dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
   
   List<Row> toBeRemovedRows = getToBeRemovedRows(sheet, dataFormatter, 4, "x");

   removeRows(sheet, toBeRemovedRows);
   
   removeEmptyRows(sheet, 3);

   workbook.write(out);
  } 
 }
}
```

The `TestIn.xlsx` looks like:

[image]

The resulting `TestOut.xlsx` then looks like:

[image]